# How change view of listiview by side wise item in yii2 listview

Tags: listview, gridview, yii2

I am using a list view in my app like

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary'=>false,
    'itemView' => '_listing'
]);?>
```

An the _listing.php is like

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="single_feature">
        <div class="single_feature_part">
            <img src="img/icon/youtube.png" alt="">
            <h4>Class 1</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After running the code it is showing like rows.each item showing in each row.But i want them like side by side.Like grid.For example listing products in amazon.in my situation i can display 4 items in a row.But my code showing only one.How can i change my code to get that result

Answer (score 1):

You can play with widget and item options provided by widget. To achieve a bootstrap four column list see the code bellow:

```
    <?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'summary' => false,
        'itemView' => '_listing',
        // options for wrapper
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'row',
        ],
        // options for each item
        'itemOptions' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'col-lg-3 col-sm-6',
        ]
    ]);?>
```

Now your _listing.php view must be following:

```
<div class="single_feature">
    <div class="single_feature_part">
        <img src="img/icon/youtube.png" alt="">
        <h4>Class 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
    </div>
</div>
```